# Robot-Plugin is Loaded again when spawning another Robot

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugin, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I recognized that every time I spawn more than one robot using `gazebo_ros_pkgs` the Plugins of the already spawned robots are reloaded (load is called again...).
Is this supposed to happen, or am I doing something wrong?

For a very small test I reduced my current launch file to this:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6104031

And start it with:

`roslaunch my_bot_gazebo test.launch robot_name:=test1 robot_namespace:=test1 x:=10`

`roslaunch my_bot_gazebo test.launch robot_name:=test2 robot_namespace:=test2 x:=-10`

I'm working with Gazebo1.9.5/ROS-Groovy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3949/robot-plugin-is-loaded-again-when-spawning-another-robot/) by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 881 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nevik](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/329/nevik/) on 2013-07-29**:
I know this might be not the best thread to post this, but the multi-instance problem is probably related to a namespace (topic name) in your robot URDF file. You will need to override this when adding more than one instance, either by overriding certain parameters in the call, or by creating slightly modified URDF files to override the namespace settings.

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2013-07-29**:
This happens with all of my robots even if I put the robotNamespace in the urdf explizitly and even with different urdfs(different robots all using different namespaces for their plugins).

btw: you can avoid the robotNamespace in the URDF-plugin part by using the `-robot_namespace` argument when calling spawn_model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The Problem was related to a Bug in the SDFFormat's urdf parser

Seems like Plugin Elements referencing the robot itself had been copied to all other robots...

The Problem is fixed in the current release...

I will mark this question as solved...

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2013-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0